# My plist returns nil when I try to access it through the Bundle.main, but I know it's there

Tags: ios, plist, swift5

I have created a .plist file named `Configuration.plist` in code. After running the app once, I can see in the file system (using the simulator) that it does exist.

[image] I

I am learning iOS development. After searching the internet for an answer on "how to read from my own plist", I keep seeing tutorials that tell me to read this file like this:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: K.files.config, ofType: "plist"),
           let xml = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: path),
           let config = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(Configuration.self, from: xml){

            print("We have a config: \(config.mainTitle)")
            return config
        } else {
            print("No config ☹️")
            return nil
        }
```

In the example above, K.files.config is just a string constant and the Configuration class conforms to the Codable protocol. The value of K.file.config is "Configuration". However, in the example above, path always returns nil. But I know this file exists!!

In fact, when I access this file like this I can actually get the path:

```
let fileName = K.files.config + ".plist"
        var filePath = ""
        
        let dirs: [String] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.allDomainsMask, true)
        
        if dirs.count > 0 {
            let dir = dirs[0]
            filePath = dir.appendingFormat("/" + fileName)
            print("Local path: \(filePath)")
        } else {
            print("Could not find local directory for Configuration.plist")
            return nil
        }
        
        if let xml = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: filePath),
           let config = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(Configuration.self, from: xml){
            print("got a config: \(config.mainTitle)")
        } else {
            print("didn't get the xml")
        }
```

This is way more verbose and ugly. Why doesn't the first method work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create `Configuration.plist` you are saving it to the Documents folder...

That folder is ***outside*** your app's bundle.

So, in your first code block, you're trying to load it *from the bundle*, which fails.

Your second code block correctly looks for and loads the file from the Documents folder.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! So, just to be sure, the documents folder is still inside my app's sandbox but not the main bundle? Then, am I saving my Configuration plist in a good place for general configuration.....(I don't want it in the Settings bundle)

Comment: @JoMomma - if you are saving "general configuration" information, sure, the Documents folder is fine. You may want to take a quick read about other folders and when / why to use them. A quick google search for `ios storage best practices` comes up with plenty of information.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I found these two articles to be really helpful for anyone who stumbles upon this thread: https://medium.com/@anandin02/ios-storage-best-practices-294fca83ad9 https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/working-with-files-and-folders-in-swift/